# Why is hovering over one CSS affecting my other CSS elements?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Let me first tender my apologies for my question might be too long to read. But I wanted to clearly explain my problem and that's why is the lengthy description of this question.
Please go through the codes that I have attached and please help me correct the mistakes.

I am an amateur designer who isn't basically into web designing but I wanted to design my own page. So taking the help of Google and going through various tutorials on the internet, I have managed to design my pages. But I am stuck at this DOWNLOAD PAGE! especially with the DOWNLOAD BUTTONS.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20461226/download%20page.jpg

This is how I intend to have my download page. When an user hovers over any particular DOWNLOAD BUTTON of any particular edition of our magazine, the wings will open up, one at the top of the download button & the other at the bottom. And when the user clicks on the button, he/she will be able to download the compressed.RAR version of that particular magazine edition.
I learnt designing this download button from "http://designshack.net/articles/css/downloadbutton/ "
and this is how the effect will be : "http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/animatedDownload/index.html  "

I managed to successfully build the individual download buttons for each edition, giving their exact locations in the CSS. But when I try to integrate all the buttons for the page into one html and one CSS, everything goes awry. 
i.e WHEN I HOVER OVER THE 1st DOWNLOAD BUTTON, instead of the wings opening up for that particular 1st download button, the wings open up at the last button!

This is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="button.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="button1">
  <a href="#">Download</a>
  <p class="top">Click to begin</p>
  <p class="bottom">7.54 MB .RAR</p>
</div>
<body>
<div class="button2">
  <a href="#">Download</a>
  <p class="top">Click to begin</p>
  <p class="bottom">7.8 MB .RAR</p>
</div>
<div class="button3">
  <a href="#">Download</a>
  <p class="top">Click to begin</p>
  <p class="bottom">7.05 MB .RAR</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

THIS IS MY CSS :

```
.button1 a {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
    left:430px;
    top:410px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 115px;
  background: #22232e;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%, #623043 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#22232e), color-stop(100%,#623043)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#22232e', endColorstr='#623043',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


  /*TYPE*/
  color: white;
  font: bold 11px/28px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

p {
  background: #5a8a37;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 105px; 
  margin: 0px 0 0 5px;

  /*TYPE*/
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 10px/25px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #0e1807;

  /*POSITION*/
  position:absolute;
    left:430px;
    top:410px;
  z-index: -1;

  /*CSS3*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
          border-radius: 3px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
          transition: all 0.4s ease;          
}


.button1:hover .top {
  margin: -23px 0 0 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.button1:hover .bottom {
  margin: 25px 0 0 5px;
}

.button1 a:active {
background: #22232e; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%, #623043 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#22232e), color-stop(100%,#623043)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#22232e', endColorstr='#623043',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/*Pulls in Wings*/
.button1:active .bottom {
  margin: 25px 0 0 5px;
}

.button1:active .top {
  margin: -23px 0 0 5px;
}


.button2 a {

  display: block;
  position:absolute;
    left:632px;
    top:410px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 115px;
  background: #22232e;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%, #623043 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#22232e), color-stop(100%,#623043)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#22232e', endColorstr='#623043',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


  /*TYPE*/
  color: white;
  font: bold 11px/28px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

p {
  background: #5a8a37;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 105px; 
  margin: 0px 0 0 5px;

  /*TYPE*/
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 10px/25px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #0e1807;

  /*POSITION*/
  position:absolute;
    left:632px;
    top:410px;
  z-index: -1;

  /*CSS3*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
          border-radius: 3px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
          transition: all 0.4s ease;          
}


.button2:hover .top {
  margin: -23px 0 0 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.button2:hover .bottom {
  margin: 25px 0 0 5px;
}

.button2 a:active {
background: #22232e; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%, #623043 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#22232e), color-stop(100%,#623043)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#22232e', endColorstr='#623043',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/*Pulls in Wings*/
.button2:active .bottom {
  margin: 25px 0 0 5px;
}

.button2:active .top {
  margin: -23px 0 0 5px;
}


.button3 a {

  display: block;
  position:absolute;
    left:833px;
    top:410px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 115px;
  background: #22232e;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%, #623043 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#22232e), color-stop(100%,#623043)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#22232e', endColorstr='#623043',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


  /*TYPE*/
  color: white;
  font: bold 11px/28px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

p {
  background: #5a8a37;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 105px; 
  margin: 0px 0 0 5px;

  /*TYPE*/
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 10px/25px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #0e1807;

  /*POSITION*/
  position:absolute;
    left:833px;
    top:410px;
  z-index: -1;

  /*CSS3*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
          border-radius: 3px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
          transition: all 0.4s ease;          
}


.button3:hover .top {
  margin: -23px 0 0 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.button3:hover .bottom {
  margin: 25px 0 0 5px;
}

.button3 a:active {
background: #22232e; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%, #623043 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#22232e), color-stop(100%,#623043)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #22232e 0%,#623043 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#22232e', endColorstr='#623043',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/*Pulls in Wings*/
.button3:active .bottom {
  margin: 25px 0 0 5px;
}

.button3:active .top {
  margin: -23px 0 0 5px;
}
```

Please guide me and help me out where is the problem and what changes need to be done.
I shall be highly obliged :) 
Regards

Comment: Before I render the HTML and CSS in my head, could you upload a live demo somewhere?

Comment: Ok, let me try upload this page's demo. I will be shortly back with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8yajE/). Why are you using different classes for the buttons? Just use `class="button"` instead of `class="button1"`, `class="button2"` and `class="button3"`.

Comment: Thank you so much @bluefire for such a fast reply. Hmm, actually I got confused with the CSS, whether to go with button1, button2 etc or with just the original class="button". Let me try incorporate the changes that you have made to the codes. Once again a whole lot of thanks :) 
Warm Regards

Comment: If you really want to use different classes, [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/JGCrh/).

Comment: @AmitPattnaik click on the blank tick beside the answer to accept it :D

Comment: Done :) 
Let me make these changes to my codes. Thank you once again.

Comment: sorry 2 bother u once again. 
I tried the changes dat u suggested bt in the CSS
.button {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
what it does is all 3 buttons r placed vertically spaced 150px apart from each other. What I am looking for is to place the 1st download button at position- left:430px; top:410px;
the 2nd dwnld button at- left:632px; top:410px;
the 3rd dwnld button at- left:833px; top:410px;
& then the 4th dwnld button at- left:430px; top:636px;
and so on. Plz help how to position the buttons?
This is how my page is ryt now: [link](http://www.aamaodisha.org/download.html)

Comment: No problem. Add another class to one of your buttons, called button1. To add multiple classes to an element, use the following syntax - `<someelement class="class1 class2 class3 etc">` - so put spaces between the class names. Then, after adding the extra class, go to your CSS and put in some positioning - for example, for your first button it would be `.button1 { position: absolute; left: 430px; top: 410px; }`. Then make similar classes for the other buttons, applying the positioning you specified above. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fdPL

Comment: Thank you so so very much.. :)) This time I got what I wanted to have.. My heartfelt thanks. Being a novice, I had been working on this particular button design & its animation since yesterday, scratching my head all through with frustration getting zero results but thanks to this site and many many thanks to you, now my problem is solved. I can't really say how relieved I am :D
Thanks a ton once again :)

Comment: Just saying, you don't seem to know much about CSS. I would suggest following [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) tutorial - there is a lot of stuff there.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Like I said, I ain't into designing sites as such but I am more into the front end designs with Photoshop. But I always have had this urge to learn and trying out new things, so I tried designing this site by myself, going through some internet tutorials and books. Prior to this, I didn't have almost any knowledge about CSS but along the way, I tried picking up the tid bits. I will surely go through the link that u have provided. If basics are known, I will be able to pick up CSS parts more easily in the future. thanks once again for all the help n guidance

Answer (score 1):

Hovering over one button element is not affecting the other button elements. It just seems that way because you've misplaced the animated `p` elements you're using for the `hover` effect.

Look more closely at the broken page. When you hover over the buttons, the filesize shown on the 3rd button changes. That's because when you hover over button #1, button #1's filesize `p` is being animated; when you hover over button #2, button #2's filesize `p` is being animated; and when you hover over button #3, *its* corresponding filesize `p` is being animated.

So the browser is doing exactly what you would expect. Only the child elements of the hovered-over button are being affected/animated.

Your real problem is that your CSS is telling them all to pop up over the 3rd button. This mistake most-likely occured when setting the absolute position of the `p.top` and `p.bottom` elements. If you inspect these DOM elements via Firebug or Chrome's DOM inspector, you'll see that they're all being placed behind button #3. Therefore, when they pop out, they pop out above/below button #3. So it looks like button #3 is being affected when you hover over button #1 & #2.

Comment: So sorry, being new to this site, I hadn't scrolled below enough to find your reply here. Yeah, I had noted the things myself that you have pointed out here but I couldn't get a way out of it.

Comment: But thanks to Bluefire, now my problem is solved and I'm feeling so relieved & happy. 
I might be seeming like I am behaving like a little child but that's how I am feeling right now, a child who has just been gifted with lots of chocolates :D